# Thread local data coming as null in commit() which I set in start() of XAResource class

Tags: weblogic, jta, distributed-transactions

`SomeClass` extends `XAResource` class here.
In `SomeClass.start()`, I am setting a `threadlocaldata` using

```
private static ThreadLocal<Xid> tlData = new ThreadLocal<Xid>();
tldata.set(Xid)
```

In `SomeClass.commit()` I am trying to get the data

```
Xid xid = tldata.get()
```

But I am getting `null`.
I do not understand why.

Comment: That would mean that `XAResource.start()` and `XAResource.commit()` are called by different threads. Have you checked the server log to diagnose what thread runs which method and (which would be interesting) get their stack traces at time of calling? I think there is no word in specification that methods `start()` and `commit()` has to be called from the same thread. I would expect that `commit()` and `prepare()` would be called from the same thread as I think the transaction object itself could be implemented as `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The XAResource.start() and XAResource.commit() are being called by the Weblogic server on which I deployed my application. I think from which threads these methods are called depends on the weblogic server and I do not have a control on it.

Comment: from what I understand the spec the `XAResource.start` and `XAResource.commit` could be called from different threads as global transaction could be disassociated from current thread and used at different one. I think that `prepare()` and `commit()` should then be called from the same thread. But it's different thing. If `SomeClass` extends `XAResource` then you don't need to save `Xid` at call of `start` method as definition of `commit` is `commit(Xid xid, boolean onePhase)`. The `XID` is provided to you at time of WebLogic calls the `commit`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a small mistake that I discovered in code. They were using the same Xid object to create a new Wrapper class in commit() and start(). So obviously the Wrapper objects were different in commit() and start().

```
XidWrapper XID = new XidWrapper(Xid);
ThreadLocal<XidWrapper> tlocal = new ThreadLocal<XidWrapper>()
commit(){
  tlocal.get(XID);
}

start() {
  tlocal.set(XID);
}
```

Note : XID is of type XidWrapper which is different than Xid (original).